# Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound when deleting and then creating nodes in parallel using transactional Neo4j REST API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I delete and then create nodes in Neo4j database (v2.1.6, Ubuntu) using the transactional REST API and auto-commit mode in parallel I get errors like this one

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound","message":"Node with id 35275"}]}
```

For each node I run the query:

```
curl -X POST -d @data http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H Accept:application/json  >out$i
```

with the following statements

```
{
    "statements": [
    {
        "statement": "MATCH (k:Keyword {kwId: \"1\"}) DELETE k",
        "parameters": {}
    },
    {
        "statement": "CREATE (k:Keyword {props}) RETURN k",
        "parameters": {
            "props": {
                "kwId": "1"
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

The kwId values are different for each query.

When I execute queries sequentially everything is fine

When I run the queries in parallel I get the error responses for some of the queries (~5 error responses for 20 queries)

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound","message":"Node with id 35275"}]}
```

Is this a Neo4j issue or I am using it wrong?

The script which reproduces the issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEO4J_URL=http://localhost:7474
TOTAL_QUERIES=20

# Create temp JSON files tmp1.json, tmp2.json, ....
for (( i=1; i<$TOTAL_QUERIES; i++ ))
do
  JSON=tmp$i.json
  cat > $JSON << END_OF_JSON
{
    "statements": [
    {
            "statement": "MATCH (k:Keyword {kwId: \"$i\"}) DELETE k",
            "parameters": {}
    },
        {
            "statement": "CREATE (k:Keyword {props}) RETURN k",
            "parameters": {
                "props": {
                    "kwId": "$i"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
END_OF_JSON
done

for (( i=1; i<$TOTAL_QUERIES; i++ ))
do
  JSON=tmp$i.json
  if [ "$1" = "sync" ]; then
    curl --silent -X POST -d @$JSON $NEO4J_URL/db/data/transaction/commit -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H Accept:application/json  >out$i  
  else
    curl --silent -X POST -d @$JSON $NEO4J_URL/db/data/transaction/commit -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8" -H Accept:application/json  >out$i &
  fi
done

wait
awk 'FNR==1{print ""}1' out* > result
grep "\"errors\":\[.*\]" result
rm out* tmp*.json result
```

Update: when using legacy REST API the error messages are better

```
  "message" : "Node with id 35970",
  "exception" : "EntityNotFoundException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.getById(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:160)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:135)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_1.TransactionBoundQueryContext$$anonfun$getNodesByLabel$1.apply(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:135)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.helpers.JavaConversionSupport$$anon$2.next(JavaConversionSupport.scala:33)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)", "scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)", "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)", "scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)", "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)", "scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)", "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)", "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)", "scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:257)", "scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1157)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.EagerPipe.internalCreateResults(EagerPipe.scala:32)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:105)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:102)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:102)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:102)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:120)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:119)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.runWithQueryState(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:168)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:118)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:103)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:68)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_1.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:67)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_1.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:159)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:76)", "org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:71)", "org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:84)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:114)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)" ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating new index on the property kwId seems to fix the errors for my case

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Keyword(kwId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but just a random thing I noticed: You're using parameters for the CREATE but not the DELETE.  I don't know if/why that might cause race conditions, but it's worth checking

Comment: Thanks Brian. I have checked DELETE parameters

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

It also seems a bit weird to be doing these two queries.  Maybe there's some confidential stuff that you stripped out, but I think you could do:

```
MATCH (k:Keyword) WHERE k.kwId IN ({kw_ids}) DELETE k WITH k.kwId AS kwId CREATE (:Keyword:  {kwId: kwId})
```

Comment: You are right. I missed all the stuff which is not related to the issue to simplify things. In a real use case the query removes nodes with existing relationships and adds new nodes with the new properties and relationships. 
I can not combine all the statements in a single query because of the legacy code (We are moving to Neo4j from other database). The nodes are processed separately and the number of nodes is quite big, about ~1 million.
Anyway, thanks Brian for your time and suggestions. I will try to explore their code to understand what happens.